# How to databind using to a 2d array of objects of different types

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got a couple of separate but related questions, and I'm new to WPF so bear with me on this.

I have a 2d array of IFarmyardSpaces, some of these are FenceSpaces, some are FieldSpaces, etc.  I basically want a grid of buttons that binds to each of these spaces, with the appropriate button styling depending on which type of IFarmyardSpace it is.

Now the questions:
1) Is it possible to easily databind what is essentially a checkerboard type of layout and have the individual items style themselves in different ways?

2) If not and I need to create and bind the buttons individually, how do I bind a button to a specific object in the 2d array?  Like if I want a button that binds to the FenceSpace that is in FarmyardSpaces[0,3]?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do both of 1). The basics are that you need an ItemsControl with each of its items being another ItemsControl (to get rows, columns). To vary the template, the easist way is to use DataTemplate resources which have a DataType and no Key instead of explicitly assigning ItemTemplate. You could also use a DataTemplateSelector, but that takes a little more code. Your templates would look something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="IFarmyardSpaces">
        <Button Style="..."/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="FenceSpaces">
        <Button Style="..."/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

And the ItemsControl like this, here using UniformGrid to get an evenly divided grid layout:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TwoDArray}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

There can be complications, like alignment if the arrays aren't all the same size, or with the templates getting applied elsewhere if you're binding the same type on another control but this should at least get you started.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.  My brain is starting to get used to the WPF style of doing things.  In case I run into it in the future, do you know if what I asked in #2 is possible?  From playing around with it, it seems like you can index into a one-dimensional array in the XAML but not into any higher dimension arrays (it gives a XAML formatting error).

Comment: Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#databinding_s for details on the different options. The syntax to get past the XAML error would be like {Binding Path=My2DArray[1\,1]} but if you're using an object[,] type collection it still might give an error. If you use a object[][] type you should be able to use a [1][1] indexing.

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar.  I was tearing my hair out trying to Google this as it seems that I'm the only fool that would want to do anything like it.

Comment: I've got this working with the UniformGrid as in your example, however I need to use a regular Grid and define the row/column sizes manually.  Been trying different things, Googling like a madman, and bashing my head against this for hours now and I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Throw up another question with the code you're trying. It is possible to do, just need to see some details.

Comment: Link to the follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638728/binding-listlistmyclass-to-cells-in-a-grid

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a IValueConverter. I have done this in a Windows 8 Metro App and bloged about it: http://jwillmer.de/blog/2012/11/02/how-to-display-different-items-in-a-gridview/

At MSDN I have found another example of the IValueConverter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/BR209903 I hope it helps to solve your problem ;-)