# Binding List<List<MyClass>> to cells in a Grid

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here's some context from a related post of mine:
[How to databind using to a 2d array of objects of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589511/how-to-databind-using-to-a-2d-array-of-objects-of-different-types)

So I have a:

```
List<List<FarmyardSpace>>
```

I want this to be represented as buttons in cells of a Grid.  I can't use UniformGrid as in the related post because I need to define the sizes of the cells in the Grid.  Ideally I don't want to have to define Row and Column fields in my data (although perhaps this should be handled by the ViewModel somehow?  Just started learning this stuff the other day and I'm still wrapping my head around WPF and MVVM).

Here's my latest attempt which does not work (and in fact throws an exception), and in this particular example I'm relying on Column and Row properties existing on the FarmyardSpaces:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FarmyardGrid}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

I think part of the reason this doesn't work is that the Items contained by the outer ItemsControl are not FarmyardSpaces but List, so they don't have a Column property to bind to.  I've also tried it with both the RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions in the inner ItemsControl.  This gets rid of the exception but also doesn't work and seems wrong to me, especially given the solution that works when using UniformGrid in the related post where the Columns are declared in the outer ItemsControl.

Anyways I'd appreciate any help figuring this out, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have properties on your collection items that specify where in the grid they go that's obviously easiest, and that's what you are set up for now. If not, you can use a converter to figure out each item's index for you and then assign that as the Row/Column value - and it can work the same in both dimensions. Here's the basic converter:

```
public class ItemToIndexConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object item = values.FirstOrDefault();
        IList collection = values.OfType<IList>().LastOrDefault();

        if (collection == null || item == null)
            return 0;

        return collection.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and modified version of your XAML (cut down to 3x3) getting the current item and the full collection from the parent ItemsControl to pass into the converter:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FarmyardGrid}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        </Grid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding>
                                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                        <local:ItemToIndexConverter/>
                                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                                    <Binding/>
                                    <Binding Path="ItemsSource"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding>
                        <MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <local:ItemToIndexConverter/>
                        </MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <Binding/>
                        <Binding Path="ItemsSource"
                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Ok I don't feel quite so bad about not getting this myself now  :)  The solution makes sense to me, but I thought there would be a less convoluted way of handling the indexing as it seems like a pretty basic thing to want to know for layout purposes.  Thanks for all the help!